# Problem with detectObjectsFromImage method

Tags: python, object-detection

I am trying to do an object detection action, where I send the program an image and it will return a new image to the specified place with the objects detected in the original image. I am following some existing code and trying to run it, but it will not let me because there is an error with the `detectObjectsFromImage` method. Specifically, the parameters for it are marked on red, which are input_image and output_image_path. They require a string, which I did give them (the path to my image), yet it is still giving me this error. I have also installed the `imageAI` library and the dependencies too using `pip`. I am not sure where the problem is, so if anyone can help, I will greatly appreciate it. The code is attached below.

```
 from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
    
    detector = ObjectDetection()
    
    model_path = "yolo-tiny.h5"
    
    input_path = "./input/sampleimage.jpg"
    
    output_path = "./output/newimage.jpg"
    
    detector.setModelTypeAsTinyYOLOv3()
    
    detector.setModelPath(model_path)
    
    detector.loadModel()
    
    detection = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=input_path, output_image_path=output_path, input_type="file", output_type="file")
    
    for eachItem in detection:
        print(eachItem["name"] , " : ", eachItem["percentage_probability"])
```

Comment: first edit question, select code and press `Ctrl+K` and it will create more readable code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you follow some example code then add url in question. If you get error then put it in question - don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides it can work correctly on our computers. And we can't read in your mind to get other information - so you have to put all details in question.

Comment: code works for me without any problem. And as for `parameters marked on red` it doesn't matter if they are marked if only code runs without errors. IDEs may have also some bugs and don't bother this.